# Center an Image in a Viewbox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Using XAML and UWP how can I center an `Image` in a `Viewbox` both vertically and horizontally? Given an image of variable dimensions, I need to scale it to the width of a container while cropping it to a specific aspect ratio.

I tried setting the width and height of the image to the desired aspect ratio and containing it in a Viewbox (as seen below) which worked except the image was aligned to the top/left (not centered) leaving all of one half but none of the other cropped.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
           Width="16"
           Height="9"
           Stretch="UniformToFill"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of it?

Comment: Note that `Stretch="UniformToFill"` cuts off either the right or bottom part of the image, depending on its natural aspect ratio. Besides that the Image control should "fill" the Viewbox so that it's centered. HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment have no effect here.

Comment: Best i can think of is having a container inside of a container, you then center the one container to the dimensions that you need and fill it with the image.

Answer (score 2):

Place the image centered and with `Stretch="UniformToFill"` inside a container that is defining the aspect ratio.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="16" Height="9">
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=ImageUrl}" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: One would expect this to work but it causes odd alignment issues, especially when scaling. I will +1 though.

Comment: @OwenJames If you can give an example where the alignment issues happen, I can look into it. As your question is now, I don't know enough about the containers and surroundings (List of images, size, layout, ...?)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution. Thank you to those who tried to help solve this problem.

The key was to set `UseLayoutRounding="False"` on the image and place it in a container, as seen below.

```
<Viewbox>
    <Grid Width="{Binding AspectWidth}"
          Height="{Binding AspectHeight}">
        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               UseLayoutRounding="False"
               Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

You may also choose to use a `Border` rather than a `Grid` as the container.